# React custom hook with state variable as parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react function component which sets an array of ids based on an user event on a link click(which opens a popup with some options that can be selected and has a callback once it is closed which will return the id of the selected element). these ids are passed to a child component which has a custom hook which uses these ids to perform some action. whenever i click on the link and select an element and close the popup..  get the error

**"VM10715 react_devtools_backend.js:2430 You have changed a parameter while calling a hook which is supposed to remain unchanged** [Array(2)]
0: (2) ["", "asdsadsad"]
lastIndex: (...)
lastItem: (...)
length: 1"

is there a way to make this work without running into this error? please see the code sample below

```
const TestComp = () => {
  const [newIds, setNewIds] = useState([]);

  const onPopupElementSelect = (ids) => {
    setNewIds([...newIds, ids]);
  };

  return (
    //renders some components
    <>
      <ImageComponent images={images} ids={newIds} onClick={handleClick} />

      <Popup onSelect={onPopupElementSelect} />
    </>
  );
};

const ImageComponent = (props) => {
  const { newIds, images } = props;
  const newImages = useImages(ids || ['']); //customhook that fetches image details by ids

  const imgs = images.map((i) => (
    <div key={i.imageId}>
      <img src={i.imageUrl} alt="" />
      <Link onClick={handleClick} /> //opens the popup for user to select a new
      image
    </div>
  ));

  return <div>{imgs}</div>;
};
```

ps: the paramerter names are not the issue.. this code is just a sample to give the basic idea of what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you gave the same name to  `parameter` and  the state may be try `newID` as the parameter name

```js
const onPopupElementSelect = (newId) => {
    setIds(oldIds => [...oldIds, newId]);
};
```

Comment: thanks for the response @NaolChala it was actually different in the original script.. that was just an example. that wasnt an issue though